# iOS sharing extension showing locally only

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I have successfully built an iOS app with a sharing extension.

On my phone connected to Xcode, both work flawlessly. However, when submitting the build to AppStoreConnect and distributing it via TestFlight, the share extension goes missing.

I have included the extension in the "General"-tab of the application under "Frameworks" and added the AppGroups for the app and the extension. What am I missing?

[image: Frameworks]

[image: App Groups]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Project > Info > Configuration

An example of what I mean:
[image: Example]
Are both debug and release targets the same on your side? I am guessing that you could have removed the share extension on your Release configuration by accident.